# Launch Popup once Page Opens (using Magnific Popup)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to have a popup (about page of the website) once the web is first launch. I am using Magnific popup - modal popup and have a hard time figuring how to do that. The popup works fine, when it is such that the website launches, then the user clicks the "about" button.

I appreciate any help given. Thanks, guys:)

script:

```
$(function () {
    $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
      type: 'inline',
      preloader: false,
      focus: '#username',
      modal: true
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.popup-modal-dismiss', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.magnificPopup.close();
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div class="html-code">
      <a class="popup-modal" href="#test-modal">about</a>

      <div id="test-modal" class="mfp-hide white-popup-block">
        <p>Change the way you think about recipes. Text link interchanges with verbs and nouns of recipes.</p>
        <p><a class="popup-modal-dismiss" href="#">Close</a></p>
      </div>
```

css:

```
.popup-modal{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:black;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    margin-left: 50px;
    bottom:0;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#test-modal{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 30px 40px;
    text-align:left;
    max-width: 650px;
    margin:40px auto;
    position:relative;

    font-size: 15pt;
    line-height: 25pt;
}

.popup-modal-dismiss{
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also open the popup directly at initialization using `.magnificPopup('open');`

```
$(function () {
    $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
      type: 'inline',
      preloader: false,
      focus: '#username',
      modal: true
    }).magnificPopup('open');

    $(document).on('click', '.popup-modal-dismiss', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.magnificPopup.close();
    });
});
```